# MVC-generating control on view from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hey...I have view for document upload. I want to have button there which will generate more uploads control on click event.Is there a way to generate controls on view from controller?
thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two possibilities:

1. When the button is clicked send an AJAX to call a controller action which will return a partial view containing a new `<input type="file" />` which upon success will be injected into the DOM
2. Directly inject into the DOM a new `<input type="file" />` when the button is clicked.

Here's an example. Suppose that you have the following markup:

```
<div id="files">
    <input type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
<a href="#" id="addfile">Add file</a>
```

and then using jquery:

```
$(function() {
    $('#addfile').click(function() {
        $('#files').append('<input type="file" name="myfile" />');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I know that controller action should be called but I don't know how to return view that will contain my control and controls that are already there

Comment: @Cipiripi, the partial view returned by the controller action will contain only a new file input.